# ubuntu 12.04 does not always boot at the first time

Tags: 12.04, boot, hard-drive

I have a recurring problem: my Ubuntu 12.4 does not always boots at once. I often get a message on a black screen, saying "Media test failure, check cable" (it is not only this what's on the screen), then I manually switch off computer and boot it again. Sometimes it goes for a few times, sometimes it boots without problem.

I also once got this message:

```
[51868,988433] Read-error on swap-device (8:0:155339776)
 [51868,990237] end_request: I/0 error, dev sda, sector 46906216
 [51869,006467] EXT4-fs (sda1): I/0 error while writing superblock
 [51869,020068] end_request: I/0 error, dev sda, sector 155376640
```

and further repeating lines "Read-error on swap-device" and "end_request: I/0 error, dev sda, sector", just with different number configurations.

I applied the same solution (switching off) and it was working again.

My hard drive might be quite old, I am using it for a year, but the computer was already second-hand, so I do not know, how long someone else was using it before me.

Computer Aspire 5100

System details: 
Release 12.4(precise) 32-bit
Kernel Linux 3.2.0-38-generic-pae
GNOME 3.4.2

**Hardware**
Memory: 1.8 GiB
Processor: AMD Turion(tm) 64 Mobile Technology MK-36

**System status**
Available disc space: 11.6 GiB

I guess that it might have to do with low disc space, total file-system capacity is 78.3 GB, total usage 79 percent (61.8 GB). How much I should free up so that computer would run without problems?

That it does not boot at once, would not be such a big problem, but I am afraid that once it will not boot at all. I have been looking at the forums and found some suggestions, but I am not sure, can I apply them to my case; I am amateur user. I would appreciate your help. Thank you very much!